# How can I fix this video phone app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm trying to practice making a simple video phone app so I'm trying to make a program to send a video and recieve a video using Cirrus from Adobe. I'm having trouble recieving the stream though. Here is the cod that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.core.mx_internal;

            import spark.components.Group;
            private const SERVER:String = "rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/";
            private const DEVKEY:String = "MY-DEV-KEY";

            [Bindable]
            //Net Connection variable
            private var netConnection:NetConnection;
            //Sending video stream var
            private var sendStream:NetStream;
            //Sending video video var
            private var videoSend:Video;
            //Receiving video stream var
            private var recvStream:NetStream;
            //String for getting their ID
            private var id_of_publishing_client:String;


            private function init():void {
                //Setup videoSend
                videoSend = new Video(320,240);
                videoSend.x = 10;
                videoSend.y = 10;
                var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                uic.addChild(videoSend);                            
                addElement(uic);
                //connect
                connect();
            }

            private function connect():void{
                netConnection = new NetConnection();
                netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamHandler);
                netConnection.connect(SERVER,DEVKEY);
            }

            private function setupStreamOutgoing():void{
                //Send Stream setting up
                sendStream = new NetStream(netConnection, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
                sendStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStreamHandler);
                //setup camera
                var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
                //attach the camera to the to the sendStream
                sendStream.attachCamera(cam);
                //publish the sendStream
                sendStream.publish("media");
                //attach the camera to the videoStream object
                videoSend.attachCamera(cam);
            }

            private function getVideoReceiver():void{
                id_of_publishing_client = theirID.text;
                writeText("inside getVideoReceiver()");
                if(id_of_publishing_client){
                    recvStream = new NetStream(netConnection, id_of_publishing_client);
                    recvStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamHandler);
                    writeText("flag");
                    //play the recvStream
                    recvStream.play("media");
                    writeText("recvStream.play(media)");
                    //attach the stream to the myVid
                    myVid.mx_internal::videoPlayer.attachNetStream(recvStream);             
                }
                else {
                    theirID.text = "Please place an ID here.";
                }

            }

            private function netStreamHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
                writeText(event.info.code);

                switch(event.info.code){
                    case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                        //Display my ID in myID.text 
                        myID.text = netConnection.nearID;
                        setupStreamOutgoing();
                        break;
                    case "NetStream.Connect.Success":
                        break;
                    case "NetStream.Connect.Closed":
                        break;

                }
            }

            private function writeText(txt:String):void{
                txtHistory.text += txt+"\n";
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextArea top="10" bottom="10" id="txtHistory" width="252" right="10"/>
    <s:TextInput id="theirID" x="112" y="342" width="437"/>
    <s:TextInput id="myID" x="112" y="312" width="437"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="312" label="My Connection" width="94" />
    <s:Button x="10" y="341" label="Their Connection" width="94" click="getVideoReceiver()"/>
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="myVid" 
                     x="340"
                     y="10"
                     width="320" height="240" />
</s:Application>
```

Inside of the `getVideoReveiver()` function I'm getting the flag to go off from `writeText("flag")` then I get and output in the text box of:

```
NetStream.Play.Reset
NetStream.Play.Start
```

from the `netStreamHandler`, but the video never shows up in the receiving video element.

I'm running this is two different videos of the same computer and taking the nearID from one stream and pasting it into the textInput `theirID`. I'm not sure what to try next?

Comment: I figured this out, I'll post the modified code as an answer later for anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that I got working for anyone who would like this as an example. All you need is a Cirrus dev key.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.core.mx_internal;
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.*;
        import flash.net.*;

        import spark.components.Group;
        private const SERVER:String = "rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/";
        private const DEVKEY:String = "YOUR-DEV-KEY";

        [Bindable]
        //Net Connection variable that is needed to s
        private var netConnection:NetConnection;
        //Sending video stream var
        private var sendStream:NetStream;
        //Sending video video var
        private var videoSend:Video;
        //receiving video video var
        private var videoRecv:Video;
        //Receiving video stream var
        private var recvStream:NetStream;
        //String for getting their ID
        private var id_of_publishing_client:String;

        private function init():void {
            //Setup videoSend
            videoSend = new Video(320,240);
            videoSend.x = 10;
            videoSend.y = 10;
            //Setup videoRecv
            videoRecv = new Video(320,240);
            videoRecv.x = 340;
            videoRecv.y = 10;
            var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
            uic.addChild(videoSend);
            uic.addChild(videoRecv);
            addElement(uic);
            //connect to cirrus
            connect();
        }

        private function connect():void{
            netConnection = new NetConnection();
            netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamHandler);
            netConnection.connect(SERVER,DEVKEY);
        }

        private function setupStreamOutgoing():void{
            //Send Stream setting up
            sendStream = new NetStream(netConnection, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
            sendStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStreamHandler);
            //setup camera
            var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
            //attach the camera to the to the sendStream
            sendStream.attachCamera(cam);
            //publish the sendStream
            sendStream.publish("media");
            //attach the camera to the videoStream object
            videoSend.attachCamera(cam);
        }

        private function getVideoReceiver():void{
            id_of_publishing_client = theirID.text;
            writeText("inside getVideoReceiver()");
            if(id_of_publishing_client){
                recvStream = new NetStream(netConnection, id_of_publishing_client);
                recvStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamHandler);
                writeText("flag");
                //play the recvStream
                recvStream.play("media");
                writeText("recvStream.play(media)");
                //attach the stream videoRecv
                videoRecv.attachNetStream(recvStream);
                }
            else {
                theirID.text = "Please place an ID here.";
            }

        }

        private function netStreamHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
            writeText(event.info.code);

            switch(event.info.code){
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                    //Display my ID in myID.text 
                    myID.text = netConnection.nearID;
                    setupStreamOutgoing();
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Connect.Success":
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Connect.Closed":
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Play.Start":
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function writeText(txt:String):void{
            txtHistory.text += txt+"\n";
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextArea top="10" bottom="10" id="txtHistory" width="252" right="10"/>
<s:TextInput id="theirID" x="112" y="342" width="437"/>
<s:TextInput id="myID" x="112" y="312" width="437"/>
<s:Button x="10" y="312" label="My Connection" width="94" />
<s:Button x="10" y="341" label="Their Connection" width="94" click="getVideoReceiver()"/>
```